# A check was given to me by my client but I realized I was doing poorly on a sole project should I reject my check salary because I felt I lack skills

Tags: professionalism, freelancing

1. it is a app project the end goal is a Uber like app but offer alot more services
2. I'm not a full timer from the company
3. It's not the main business of the company
4. Im more optimistic on this project.
5. Sadly They felt I was slow and it might be costly for the company to continue.
6. They had to divert me to their main business projects except I was doing even more poorly too which to me this is worser than my current project i was  already working on. This is due to the new technology I have to learn on my own.
7. The project I originally I was working on don't have investors yet. Unlike their core business.
8. But The company wants to explore new technology besides their current business
9. If I pass and i was able to build and rewrite current  business software then they will let me in as a permanent because that is their earning comes
   Feels like I rather not take the pay for project because I feel like I'm disappointing people they have high expectations from me.
10. They felt like it shouldn't have taken that longer than a website even for me. They are expecting a completed project before i got the check execpt they said it's far from complete that's why they forced the switch project
11. To them the current project im working on is experimental.
12. Should I accept that I failed to meet deadline? And reject the pay that supposed to be the pay for a fully completed project.

Comment: For heaven's sake, you _never_ reject pay. How can you even think about this?

Comment: "They felt like it shouldn't have taken that longer than a website even for me", didn't you *estimate* how much it would take?

Comment: I know it's stupid to reject

Comment: Apps are slow to make and got complicated

Answer (score 4):

Do not reject this payment. The company took a risk on an experimental project and it didn't work out, this is the cost of doing business.  It is very common for the cost of a project to increase to such a point that the project is cancelled, and the original budget is spent with no final product to show for it.

Regardless of how you feel about your abilities in this case, the reality is you were the person they chose for this task, and as long as you did not commit some kind of misrepresentation or outright fraud you are entitled to be paid for your efforts.

Answer (score -1):

Morally yes but ethically no! You provide a service and you do deserve to get paid for that. Now whether or not it was profitable that is the risk they took when they signed you up. But it all comes down what the agreement terms states. I would however return the difference if the contract was not fulfill. Only because you want to leave in good terms. Don't burn bridges.

Comment: Paying back even the difference is the same as having "mug" tattooed on your forehead in big letters. You are not leaving on good terms. You _are_ actually burning bridges because you demonstrate stupidity, and I wouldn't rehire anyone that stupid. If I was the one who hired you, and we met at a different company, I'd say "don't hire him, he's weird".